# how to copy just the table structure from one user to another using SQL

Tags: oracle9i

Please help me with this question. Am trying to copy the table structure from one user to another in SQL 9i. Can you help me with how to do this. i have a fair bit of idea of how to copy a table from one user to another but i dont know how to just copy the table structure wth no records.

Answer (score 1):

oracle:

```
create table new_table as select * from old_table where 0 = 1
```

sql server:

```
select * into new_table from old_table where 0 = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle9i, we can also copy the table structure from following query:

```
create  table  copy_course as 
select  *  from course where 1=2;
```